# How do you remove the bed icons on Google Maps V3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to not show these icons on the maps embedded in my website:-

[image]

Does anyone know what the API call is. I have looked through https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference and have had no luck at all.

Comment: Only the bed icons or also the church, fork and knife?

Comment: I can live with them all going but ideally only the bed.

Comment: Just for reference, the code in @duncan's answer makes use of three different parts of the API: [MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions), [MapTypeStyle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyle), and [MapTypeStyler](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyler).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are Googles POI's.  Not sure of the sub-type (see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType), but you can disable all types of POIs from appearing using something like this:

```
var myStyles =[
    {
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [
              { visibility: "off" }
        ]
    }
];

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.42838,-2.9623),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: myStyles 
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

In fact the beds fall under the '[poi.business](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/business-icons-and-styling-across.html)' sub-type, which will also prevent things like shops showing up, if you use:

```
 featureType: "poi.business",
```