# google maps remove interactions with unneeded elements

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am working on application which uses google maps.

When I zoom the map closer, a lot of useless (for the purpose of my app) appears. Here is the example:[image].

Not only I do not need any of the `Casa Salvador`, `Liquid`, `Valeria Peluqueros` things, they are also interactive (the mouse is changing on hover, you can click and popup appears).

I thought that I can easily disable them through [google maps options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions), where I can disable default user interface and a lot of other things, but I failed to find any option related to my needs.

Does anyone have an idea how to:

- completely remove the elements I listed
- make them visible but not interactive

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you remove the bed icons on Google Maps V3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796958/how-do-you-remove-the-bed-icons-on-google-maps-v3)

Comment: Regarding your second query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950030/can-i-remove-just-the-popup-bubbles-of-pois-in-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: @Salvador-Dali - you can't make them visible but not interactive uness you cover them with something transparent that blocks clicks (see the comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466805/google-maps-api-click-point-marker-not-custom/13466933#13466933)

Answer (score 1):

I have been going through the same problem. 
1. To remove them you have apply custom styles to your map.

```
var styleArray = [
  {
    featureType: "poi.business",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
];
map.setOptions({styles: styleArray});
```

This will remove all the business labels. For more help:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#creating_a_styledmaptype

2. exactly your answer I guess: http://jsfiddle.net/mrak/dHWVM/

Regards

Suyash